# Plans to use Vendor ID to identify EtherCAT devices?

Tags: ros

I also asked this question on [ROS Answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/52182/plans-to-use-vendor-id-to-identify-ethercat-devices/), but it's not getting much interest there.

Currently the EtherCAT package in ROS uses the slaves' Product IDs to identify the devices, and load the correct drivers. This works great when all of the devices are manufactured by a single vendor, but are there any plans to prevent Product ID collisions when multiple vendors make ROS compatible EtherCAT devices?

We manufacture our own EtherCAT devices, and are just using some large values for Product ID, just hoping that these don't collide with anyone else's. Ideally, ROS would concatenate the vendor and product IDs into a single 64-bit value, and use that to identify the correct driver.

Comment: This is quite specific to ROS and the EtherCAT package, meaning that only the package maintainer would be able to give a proper answer to the question. An appropriate answer was already given in ROS Answers, suggesting the enhancement request... I vote for closing this question as too localized.

Answer (score 2):

That certainly is problematic. Given that ROS is free software, you could probably quite easily change the source code to use the `<vendor_id, product_code>` pair as identifier and send a pull request.